# How to do this while loop

Tags: javascript

```
var understand = true;    
while( ){
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");    
    understand = false;
}
```

What should I add in the parentheses to make it print "I'm learning while loops!"

Comment: This is a trivial question, with a rather obvious answer. What have you tried?

Comment: You can achieve the same result with `do while()`

Comment: Are you following through a JavaScript tutorial?

Comment: I don't understand you people why minus the mark for some simple questions, I am learning, I am new, you didn't ever ask easy question?!!?!?!

Comment: I am doing codecademy.

Comment: Questions so easy shows you did not even attempt to find the answer yourself.  There are a plethora of examples available most likely from whatever source you're using to find the `while` loop in the first place

Comment: Your answer surely will be in the first page of any book/tutorial you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `understand` inside the parens will make it print `"I'm learning while loops!"` then stop (due to `understand` being set false after printing).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the statement in the while loop:

```
var understand = true;    
while( understand ){ //while understand == true
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");    
    understand = false;
}
```

look more about while statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)